# How can I fetch the list of the active block producers and standby block producers using eosjs?

Tags: block-producer, javascript

At this time, is it possible for me to do so when the BPs have not been elected? I need this for a block explorer I'm building using eosjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with eosjs.

You can create an instance of `Eos` with a given `config` and then do `getTableRows` with the given parameters. You might find the [api footprint here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-api/blob/master/src/api/v1/chain.json). Also check [the github repository](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs) for more info about the config parameters.

Here is an example how I do it at [EOSIO BP alarm](https://eossweden.se/bpalarm):

```
eos = new Eos(config)
eos.populateBlockProducers().then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        }, this.handleError)

eos.getTableRows({
            "json": true,
            "scope": 'eosio',
            "code": 'eosio',
            "table": "producers",
            "limit": 500
        })

function populateBlockProducers() {
        return eos.getTableRows({
            "json": true,
            "scope": 'eosio',
            "code": 'eosio',
            "table": "producers",
            "limit": 500
        })
    }

function handleError(error) {}
```